# How to display database values in a popup dialog?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a Popup Dialog in which I need to display few values that are in database. The same is being displayed in parent activity of the dialog.

But when I use the same, I am getting error.

Code:

Dialog -

```
<Dialog
    visible={this.state.showDialog}
    title="Custom Dialog"
    onTouchOutside={() => this.openDialog(false)}
    contentStyle={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }}
    animationType="fade">

    <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize:22, textAlign:'center', color: '#000' }}>User Details</Text>

    <Text style={{ color: '#000'  }}>Customer Name : {this.state.userDetails.Details[0].name}</Text>

    <Button onPress={() => this.createPDF(this.state.userDetails)} style={{ marginTop: 10, color: '#000' }} title="Proceed" />
</Dialog>
```

Database Details (Working) -

```
<View style={[styles.container, { marginTop:30 }]}>
  {
      this.state.userDetails ?
      <View>
         <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize:22, textAlign:'center', color: '#000' }}>User Details</Text>
         <View style={{ marginLeft:40, marginTop:15 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#000'  }}>Name : {this.state.userDetails.Details[0].name}</Text>
         </View>
      </View>
   :
   <Text>Loading...</Text>
  }
</View>
```

For the above, I am getting this error -

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.userDetails.Details[0]')

Comment: is $ required before {this.state.userDetails.Details[0].name} in case of dialog?

Comment: That was a typo. Even without $ I'm getting the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you're rendering the **Database Details**, by checking if the `this.state.userDetails` is `true` and in the former, **Dialog** there is no check.

Therefore you can add a simple check as

```
<Text style={{ color: '#000'  }}>Customer Name : {this.state.userDetails && this.state.userDetails.Details[0].name}</Text>
```